Terragrunt terragrunt-source-map seems not to replace anything
I have a complex Terragrunt setup. Terragrunt fetches Terraform modules from a remote git repository. For development purposes, I would love to replace one of the remote modules with a local replacement. When I use the following command nothing changes and the output is as below. What do I do wrong?
Command
terragrunt --terragrunt-source-map git::ssh://git@git.lony.xy/ops/terraform_modules.git=/Users/lony/Desktop/source_map --terragrunt-source-update apply

Output
Initializing modules...
Downloading git::ssh://git@git.lony.xy/ops/terraform_modules.git?ref=develop for data_org...
- data_org in .terraform/modules/data_org/modules/data_org


I believe a there might be a syntax error with the source. Could you try using:
terragrunt --terragrunt-source-map git::git@git.lony.xy/ops/terraform_modules.git=/Users/lony/Desktop/source_map --terragrunt-source-update apply

Thanks a lot, sadly I have the setup no longer handy. I test it as soon as I face the problem once again!
